# SQL MS Access Summing Results Based on Two Table Criteria

Tags: sql, join, ms-access-2007

I've been asked to find if totals from one table exceed a certain value. However the identifier I need to group these is stored in another table. So I've figured how to isolate what I need and then copy into excel. However I do understand the principle of summing in SQL, as I've made my own queries that look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT ID, SUM(Table1.Amount) AS Subtotal FROM Table1 WHERE LineNumber = 1 GROUP BY ID) AS a, Table2 AS b
WHERE a.ID = b.ID 
AND a.Subtotal > b.Threshold
```

In this case, the totals I need to sum all have the same LineNumber from the original table (Table1) so it's easy to compare to a value in a different table. What I want to do is be able to is join a subquery back to the original table, then GROUPBY the identifier and sum from the *other* table, adding a criteria that the original ID from table one must be a duplicate:

```
SELECT * FROM 
((Table1 as t 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT ID FROM Table1 
GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(ID) >1) as b
ON t.ID = b.ID
```

Joining criteria back to the original table, I need to do this because the table I need to sum doesn't contain ID,

```
INNER JOIN Table2 as c
ON t.ID2 = c.ID2
WHERE c.LineNumber = 4
```

This is where I'm stuck. I want to sum all the LineNumber = 4 for each ID. Again, I had to join using ID2 because ID1 isn't in Table2

Perhaps I'm making this too complicated? Any suggestions would be welcome

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give an example of your schema/data?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not too experienced with databases in general.